# How can I fill the shape it has tow holes in python use turtle

Tags: python

I want to fill it in once and get something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDmYb.png)

but I got result like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7B5U.png)

Thank you all.

and this is my code:

```
my_tu = turtle.Turtle()
    my_tu.screen.screensize(500, 500)
    my_tu.color('#000000', '#bbbbbb')

    my_tu.penup()
    my_tu.goto(-200, 200)
    my_tu.begin_fill()
    my_tu.pendown()
    my_tu.goto(200, 200)
    my_tu.goto(200, -200)
    my_tu.goto(-200, -200)
    my_tu.goto(-200, 200)

    my_tu.penup()
    my_tu.goto(-170, 170)
    my_tu.pendown()
    my_tu.goto(-130, 170)
    my_tu.goto(-130, 130)
    my_tu.goto(-170, 130)
    my_tu.goto(-170, 170)

    my_tu.penup()
    my_tu.goto(0, 170)
    my_tu.pendown()
    my_tu.goto(40, 170)
    my_tu.goto(40, 130)
    my_tu.goto(0, 130)
    my_tu.goto(0, 170)

    my_tu.end_fill()
```

how can i fix this?

Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

I try to back to each shape start point. At last back to the end point. it works! but I thought this is not good method. Has a good way to fix this?

Below is the code:

```
my_tu = turtle.Turtle()
my_tu.screen.screensize(500, 500)
my_tu.color('#000000', '#bbbbbb')

my_tu.penup()
my_tu.goto(-200, 200)
my_tu.begin_fill()
my_tu.pendown()
my_tu.goto(200, 200)
my_tu.goto(200, -200)
my_tu.goto(-200, -200)
my_tu.goto(-200, 200)
my_tu.penup()

my_tu.goto(-170, 170)
my_tu.pendown()
my_tu.goto(-130, 170)
my_tu.goto(-130, 130)
my_tu.goto(-170, 130)
my_tu.goto(-170, 170)
my_tu.penup()

my_tu.goto(0, 170)
my_tu.pendown()
my_tu.goto(40, 170)
my_tu.goto(40, 130)
my_tu.goto(0, 130)
my_tu.goto(0, 170)
my_tu.penup()

my_tu.goto(-170, 170)
my_tu.goto(-200, 200)
my_tu.goto(0, 170)

my_tu.end_fill()
```

Comment: Please edit your question with the relevant info from this answer if your problem is not solved or you want to improve it